# bigquery MERGE DML with correlated subquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to have a correlated query (a subquery inside one of the WHEN clauses in MERGE) using the MERGE DML in bigQuery?

See for example an adapted query that I found googling for 'MERGE WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE DELETE' below. Notice the two SELECTS inside the WHEN clauses:

```
MERGE Target1 AS T
USING Source1 AS S
ON (T.label_id = S.label_id) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.project_name IN (SELECT DISTINCT(project_name) FROM Source1) 
    THEN INSERT(attr1, attr2) VALUES(S.attr1, S.attr2)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.attr1 = S.attr1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.project_name IN (SELECT DISTINCT(project_name) FROM Source1)
    THEN DELETE  ;
```

How can this be done in bigQuery? Does it need modifying from my query above?
I currently get a:
`Correlated subquery is unsupported in WHEN clause.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, subqueries within a WHEN clause [are not supported for MERGE statements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#limitations) in BigQuery.

There's a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905927) with a [similar scenario](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905927#comment9) and a [workaround](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905927#comment14) that might be helpful to you.